# Stripe Checkout Loading Indicator Does Not Go Away

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe's custom integration, I know in their example they are adding an event listener, but in my javascript code I am skipping that, not sure if that is why the loading indicator never goes away when someone closes out of it.

Here is my code:

```
 var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: 'tests',
                image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
                locale: 'auto',
                token: function(token) {
                    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
                    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.



                },


closed: function() {
                // Close Checkout on page navigation:
                closehandler();

            }
        });
        handler.open({
            name: 'Jungle Exchange',
            description: 'Get your Amazon On!',
            amount: amount
        });

        function closehandler() {
            handler.close();
        }
```

When clicking on the x for the modal, the loading icon does not disappear from the center of the screen and overlays everything. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That seems unexpected! I'd recommend writing into Stripe support with the exact URL with this happened and different things you've tried, as well as any errors in your Web Inspector console.

https://support.stripe.com/email/login